# sweet.js cannot return #`else`

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

**main.js**

```
import {另} from './chinese-macros';
另 {
}
```

**chinese-macros.js**

```
export syntax 另 = function(ctx) {
    return #`else`;
}
```

main.js should compile to `else {}` but I get this error message instead:

```
throw this.createError(start, "not a valid expression");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else {}` by itself is an invalid expression, that's why you're receiving that error message. What (I believe) you're doing is trying to replace *if* and *else* into Chinese. So assuming you've made a macro for an if statement, the compiler will end up evaluating the macro for if, **then separately** evaluating for the else macro.

What you should do instead is build up a macro for the `if/else-if/else` statement in one macro, much like how the tutorial builds one for a `cond` expression: http://sweetjs.org/doc/1.0/tutorial.html#_sweet_cond. Notice how they iterate through keywords starting with `case` then `default`, and throwing an error if none of those two appear (invalid syntax). It's the same idea for what you want to achieve except doing `if`, `else if`, and `else` in that order... while adding more error handling and accounting for the different syntax.